# enter you credentials to connect to the following webservice infopath

Tags: infopath, web-services, administration

Im trying to open an infopath form from Sharepoint and I am getting the following error: "enter you credentials to connect to the following webservice infopath"

please advice

Comment: There might be a lot of reasons and this topic is pretty searchable on internet

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, could you please elaborate on this?
* Are you using a SharePoint webservice in your form?
* Are you using a custom web service in your form?

Ensure you have selected Domain under Form Options > Security and Trust level. Republish the form and check if it works.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I was trying to connect to a list with restricted permissions. that is why i was getting the error. but now it is fixed.